# trouble importing the hanzi-writer module in node js

Tags: node.js, import

sorry for the noob question - [HanziWriter](https://github.com/chanind/hanzi-writer) works great for me when I include it using a script tag. but when I try to import the module by doing the following in my node.js project

import {  HanziWriter }  from 'hanzi-writer';

var hanziWriter = new HanziWriter('target-div', '我', {
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        showOutline: true,
        showCharacter: false,
        strokeAnimationDuration: 1000,
        delayBetweenStrokes: 0,
        showHintAfterMisses: 1
    });

i get the javascript error

"_hanziWriter.HanziWriter is not a constructor"

I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which node version you are using?

Comment: 6.9.1 .. I am also using create-react-app if that's relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was an issue with hanzi-writer that the creator has fixed. all good.
https://github.com/chanind/hanzi-writer/issues/13